# How could one prevent named making recursive queries?

Tags: server, dns, bind

I have my bind9 configuration:

```
acl allowed {
        192.168.12.0/24;
        10.10.0.0/24;
};
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.12.90; 10.10.0.21; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };

        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        allow-notify { localnets; };
        allow-query     { none; };
        allow-recursion { allowed; };
        allow-query-cache { allowed; };
        allow-transfer { 192.168.12.117; };
        allow-update { none; };
        blackhole {  none; };

        forward only;
        forwarders {
                192.168.12.4;
        };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
```

With this configuration I allowed clients make recursive queries that bind should resolve by forwarding to another DNS server.
I do a trace:

```
dig @192.168.12.90 wikipedia.org +trace
```

Get: 
It outputs long trace having at the bottom:

```
wikipedia.org.          600     IN      A       91.198.174.192
;; Received 86 bytes from 208.80.154.238#53(ns0.wikimedia.org) in 140 ms
```

It is obviously that the local DNS server performs recursive queries starting from root servers down to ns0.wikimedia to do the resolution, although it was commanded to only forward queries(**`forward only;`** directive).

**How could one stick to pure forwarding without allowing DNS server do recursive queries?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `dig` manual:

> **+[no]trace** - Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name servers for the name being looked up. Tracing is disabled by default.
>   When tracing is enabled, **dig makes iterative queries to resolve the
>   name being looked up**. It will follow referrals from the root servers,
>   showing the answer from each server that was used to resolve the
>   lookup.

So to check if your server supports recursive queries or not, just run:

`#dig @192.168.12.90 wikipedia.org`

and see if the RA(Recursion Available) bit is set in the response header.

e.g. for Google DNS server

```
#dig @8.8.8.8 wikipedia.org
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

Comment: Yes, it does recursive queries, as it seems to be affected by +trace flag.
But I also specified **forward only;** in configuration file. One could expect that bind with that option would not make iterative queries..
Or it's dig who does iterative queries and not bind?

Comment: Yes, this is the way that dig +trace works.
See this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/715632/how-does-dig-trace-actually-work)

Comment: To be sure: dig does several recursive queries until gets the result by querying them to local DNS server which in turn forwards that queries to some upper, for instance, provider's DNS server?

Comment: Not exactly, with the command `dig @192.168.12.90 wikipedia.org +trace`, your local resolver will make iterative queries until he finds the record that are looking for. 
`@192.168.12.90` is used only in the initial query, to reply to local resolver back with a referral to root servers(e.g. e.root-servers.net).
Next, the local resolver will query the root servers (e.root-servers.net in this case) and will receive next DNS server - (a0.org.afilias-nst.info) and so on.. The process will continue until the local resolver will receive DNS server that hosts the wikipedia.org zone).

Comment: As I know, by default on Ubuntu there's _stub resolver_ that couldn't make iterative queries itself, but can only make queries to servers listed in resolv.conf. "local resolver will query the root servers " it seems like incorrect statement.

Comment: Sorry, I used "local resolver" to describe how iterative queries work theoretically. Like I said, iterative queries are made by dig on the local station, one by one, initially towards the `server` and later towards other servers returned. resolv.conf srv have the following purpose in the 4 iterative queries described above: a.in the first query as default DNS srv(when the `server` is omitted in dig +trace command) b.to find out the IP addresses of name servers returned at each iterative request (root srv, .com srv,etc) You can check this using wireshark

Comment: And how "forward only;" first in the picture? Do named just resolves "IP addresses of name servers returned at each iterative request" by forwarding queries to some other DNS server, like IPS's one?

Comment: What server exactly do you mean by `server`?

Comment: In the comments above I meant strictly on how dig + trace works. `server` is the `@server` from dig + trace command.
Related to your server configuration, `forward:only` and `forwarders {}` options are enough to do what you are expecting
(to forward all requests to an outside resolver). 
Your external resolver(192.168.12.4) will do recursive queries for you and return results to 192.168.12.90 and then back to you.